# PyO3 turn TryFrom errors into PyErr

Tags: rust, pyo3

I'm trying to write a Python wrapper to some Rust code, which does some `TryFrom` conversions internally:

```
pub enum MicrophoneType {
    Bidirectional,
    Omnidirectional,
}

impl TryFrom<char> for MicrophoneType {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(x: char) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match x {
            'b' => Ok(Self::Bidirectional),
            'o' => Ok(Self::Omnidirectional),
            _ => Err("MicrophoneType: Invalid character given"),
        }
    }
}

#[pyfunction]
fn compute(
    _py: Python,
    microphone: char,
) -> PyResult<()> {
    let _microphone = MicrophoneType::try_from(microphone)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

However I'm seeing the error message

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `PyErr`
  --> rir_generator_py/src/lib.rs:59:59
   |
58 | ) -> PyResult<()> {
   |      ------------ expected `PyErr` because of this
59 |     let _microphone = MicrophoneType::try_from(microphone)?;
   |                                                           ^ the trait `From<&str>` is not implemented for `PyErr`
```

and I am confused as to why.

It seems that PyO3 does not know what to do with the type `type Error = &'static str;` in my `impl`, right? But isn't that the default way of giving error messages? Shouldn't PyO3 expect these, if it's a common pattern? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [finding these docs](https://pyo3.rs/v0.19.2/function/error_handling#foreign-rust-error-types) I've realized a few things things:

Firstly, it's not a good pattern to use `type Error = &'static str;`, instead you should use a custom error that can be `match`ed and `From`/`Into`ed, if needed

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct InvalidMicrophoneCharError {}

impl Error for InvalidMicrophoneCharError {}

impl fmt::Display for InvalidMicrophoneCharError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Incorrect microphone character")
    }
}

impl TryFrom<char> for MicrophoneType {
    type Error = InvalidMicrophoneCharError;

    fn try_from(x: char) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match x {
            'b' => Ok(Self::Bidirectional),
            'o' => Ok(Self::Omnidirectional),
            _ => Err(InvalidMicrophoneCharError {}),
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, you have to use the [newtype pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html) to create a "`From`-chain" that starts with your type and ends with a `PyErr`, which can then be combined with PyO3's support for Rust-native `Result<T, E>`s:

```
struct MyInvalidMicrophoneCharError(InvalidMicrophoneCharError);

impl From<MyInvalidMicrophoneCharError> for PyErr {
    fn from(err: MyInvalidMicrophoneCharError) -> Self {
        PyValueError::new_err(err.0.to_string())
    }
}

impl From<InvalidMicrophoneCharError> for MyInvalidMicrophoneCharError {
    fn from(other: InvalidMicrophoneCharError) -> Self {
        Self(other)
    }
}

#[pyfunction]
fn compute(
    _py: Python,
    microphone: char,
) -> Result<(), MyInvalidMicrophoneCharError> {
    let _microphone = MicrophoneType::try_from(microphone)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

or skip the chain and simply use `map_err()`

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn compute(
    _py: Python,
    microphone: char,
) -> Result<(), MyInvalidMicrophoneCharError> {
    let _microphone = MicrophoneType::try_from(microphone)
        .map_err(|error| PyValueError::new_err(error.to_string()))?;

    Ok(())
}
```